# Adding a UIMenuItem doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with two UITextView's in each cell and want to add a custom menu item, when text is selected. What I did in my CollectionViewCell-class:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    var menuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()

    var translateSelectionItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Translate", action: "translateSelection")
    menuController.menuItems = NSArray(array: [translateSelectionItem])
}
```

But the item doesn't show up in the menu. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

It takes more than creating the custom menu item. To make the custom menu item actually appear, the first responder must also return `true` from `canPerformAction:withSender:` for this action, and of course there must be an implementation of the action method as well.

Comment: For example, here is sample code for a text field that can make an "Expand" menu item appear when its text is selected. The menu item is created here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p526textFieldDelegate/ch23p810textFieldDelegate/ViewController.swift But the code to make the menu item _appear_ is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p526textFieldDelegate/ch23p810textFieldDelegate/MyTextField.swift

Comment: Nice, dug for hours and only found obj-c examples which got me lost. Looking at this now.

Comment: Works perfectly. Didn't realize I had to apply the action on the textfield class since I am referencing it in the view controller... Seems javascript scopes have been drilled into my head for too long...  Have to wait 23 more hours before awarding bounty Thanks!